# Using Native UISearchBar to search a place on WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm still a beginner with Objective C
I developed a website using cakephp and I used a paid api for the map
Now I'm trying to build an iOS app but they don't have an iOS api so I only need to display the map into WKWebView
I removed all the buttons and created native buttons
I succeed to to inject JS to the native buttons using **evaluateJavaScript** and it works fine 
But now I created an UISeachBar on the navigation bar and I'm using

**- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText**

I want to send the searchText to a JS function and then return an array
the problem is that when I created a JS function just for testing I get this message when I type String  :

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
```

But when I type numbers it works fine

My Objc code :

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"getSuggest(%@)", searchText];
    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:function completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
         NSLog(@"Result %@",result);
     }];
}
```

My JS code :

```
var getSuggest = function(searchText) {
   return searchText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to embed the `searchText` into *""* for the js function call:

```
NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"getSuggest(\"%@\")", searchText];
```